# Magento 2 issue on header minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, knockoutjs

Im having problem on integrating header mini cart into my custom theme. The mini cart is not showing the recently added items. Below are the screenshots of the issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Parent theme: Magento/Blank

Screenshots: 
[image]

[image]

By the way I'm newbie for Magento 2.

Comment: Please edit your question and repost the full question here on Magento SE. On SO they might close or delete your question and then we do not have the info anymore.